# Django: Error when saving a string in a foreign key field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and I want to save data that comes from an Android application to Django server. I have two models in Django:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    route_key = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.route_key
```

and:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    track_route_key = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    delivery = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    track = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.delivery
```

I have this serializer:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = '__all__'
```

And I am getting data in this POST method in views.py:

```
class TrackList(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = TrackSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In Android, I create a JSONObject and is what I am sending to server.

The thing is, if I only send the attributes 'delivery' and 'track' from Android, I can save the values without any error, but if I also send the 'route_key', it gives me a 400 bad request, but I am receiving the data.

This is what I received on the server, 3 strings.

```
{'delivery': 'Miriam', 'track_route_key': '22', 'track': '(43.30725, -2.010733, 10 jul. 2017 17:40:40)'}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
[10/Jul/2017 17:40:55] "POST /listroutes/ HTTP/1.1" 400 67
```

I am sure that the error occurs when validating the 'track_route_key' field. How can I convert the 'track_route_key' string to a Foreign Key and save this value?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Foreign Key`(s) are mapped to `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` ([docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)) so you shouldn't have to convert `track_route_key`. Are you sure the error is for validating that field? More information would be helpful, configure logging and it will tell you what the issue is. You could also try deserialize that data in the shell.

Comment: You  need to show concrete error message from server

Comment: I finally managed to create the object, I forgot to add this line to serializer class. `track_route_key = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)`. But now, in Django Rest Api view, this fields appear as null.